# How do I find the serial number and other important information of an old airplane I have?

Tags: aircraft-certification

My dad has passed away and I have his plane. I can't find the paper work but I want to get a replacement title from FAA. Their site says that I need manufacturer name, model designation, N-number, and serial number.  I have the N-number but don't know where to find the other info. Could you please help me find that information?

Comment: Is there a packet of paperwork inside the aircraft? Usually there is the airworthyness certificate, registration and manual. Sometimes the manuals also have the serial number on them if they are original. You can also look in the airframe/engine logbooks if you can locate them.

Comment: There should be a placard with the serial number on or near a primary structural member, like the wing spar or a firewall. If you can be more detailed about the plane (manufacturer, type), we might be more specific. Please type the N-number into [this site](http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/NNum_Inquiry.aspx) and add the information from there to your question.

Comment: I will try looking for that primary structure.  The wings are off in the garage.  My mom says she had the paper work somewhere. :( but can't find it.  I did go to that web site and typed in the N number and it came up, "attention, this aircraft's status may not be suitable for operation"  I contacted the number and I got the automated runaround.

Comment: If you have trouble finding the paperwork, or if you're not sure what the aircraft is, I suggest you take a couple of photos and add them to your question. That would help us to identify the aircraft type and where the serial number is likely to be.

Comment: I have a picture, how do I attach it to this comment?  The N number is 97554

Comment: The aircraft is a [Stinson 108](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinson_108) (a beautiful airplane when restored). Serial number 108-554. It should also be noted that it is listed as having multiple owners, you may want to try to contact those people. Just use the N-Number look up that @PeterKämpf gave, except under the warning message, click the "continue" link.

Comment: oh yes, my mom mentioned something about multiple owners.  hmm.  thanks so much for your help!!!

Comment: yes, looked it up, and got all the info

Comment: When you finish all the look up can you put all processes you went through as answer? That be helpful to others :)

Comment: Do you have the log books for the plane (as you state you dont have the paperwork)? If you intend on bringing this plane back into service or sell it, you will (for all intents and purposes) need the log books along with all the registration documents.

Answer (score 3):

There are three pieces of paper the FAA issues which would fall under the concept of "title" to an aircraft.

The first is an aircraft lien (typically held by a bank when you take out a loan collateralized by the aircraft). This is probably not what you're looking for, but you should inquire as to whether any liens are held against the aircraft before doing any work, just to be sure you have "clear title" to the results of your work.

The second is an [Aircraft Registration Certificate](https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/aircraft_certification/aircraft_registry/) - this is a record tying the N number (in your case [N97554](http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/NNum_Results.aspx?nNumberTxt=97554)) to the aircraft itself.
In your case the registration is Revoked, so once reassembled the aircraft would need to be re-registered to be flown. [This would be a "Call your local FSDO" situation](http://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/field_offices/fsdo/) - Presumably the registration was revoked when the aircraft registry changed to a 3-year expiring registration period.  Also as there are multiple owners listed on the registration re-registering may require more work.

The final piece of paper you need is an Airworthiness Certificate - this should be in the aircraft, and is valid forever. If it's not in the plane [you can get a replacement](http://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/aircraft_certification/aircraft_registry/aircraft_faq/) - again, contact your local FSDO.

If you need information you don't have, or want to confirm it before talking to the FAA, look for the aircraft data plate. On Stinson aircraft (going by the N number you provided) the data plate is usually located on the firewall above the copilot rudder pedals as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbMP0.jpg).
On newer metal aircraft it is often located on the tail, under the horizontal stabilizer.

For more information on the aircraft itself check out [stinsonflyer.com](http://www.stinsonflyer.com/ac-0.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: this question was already answered in the op comments.

Type the N number into the FAA registry [here](http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/NNum_Inquiry.aspx).  It will give you all of the aircraft registration info including the serial number, make, model, and year.